# how can i know how many episode of a movie do i have in my file

Tags: python, file, operating-system

i wanna know how many episode of a movie i have in my file.
the name of episodes are something like this:
"name.S01E01.720p.WEB-DL.mkv", "name.S01E02..."
i think i should use something like this but idk what's next

```
import os
with os.scandir(path) as files:
    for file in files:
    ...
```

but every movie has a specific name (for example)"name.Joint.Economic.Area.S01E01.720p.NF.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV" or some thing else and i wanna write a code that would work with any kind of names

i think the way that im doing this is not a professional way to do it.

i used this one:

```
import os
with os.scandir(path) as files:
    for file in files:
        num = 01
        if any(str(num) in file.name):
            print("yes")
```

but i got an error.

Comment: The error you got was a SyntaxError. Did you figure out why that was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import glob
import os,sys
import re
import json
try:
  movie_path_orig = sys.argv[1]
except:
  print(f"use ./{sys.argv[0]} <movie path>")
  sys.exit(0)

movie_path = os.path.join(movie_path_orig, "*.mkv")

print(f"Processing {movie_path}..")
files = glob.glob(movie_path)

summary = {}
for f in files:
  r=re.search("^(.*)S([0-9]{2})E([0-9]{2})(.*)", f)
  prefix = r.group(1)
  s = int(r.group(2)) #season
  e = int(r.group(3)) #episode
  suffix = r.group(4)
  if prefix not in summary.keys():
    summary[prefix] = { 'seasons': { f"{s}": e }, 'prefix': prefix, 'suffix': suffix}
  else:
    if f"{s}" not in summary[prefix]['seasons'].keys():
       summary[prefix]['seasons'][f"{s}"] = e
    else:
       summary[prefix]['seasons'][f"{s}"] = max(summary[prefix]['seasons'][f"{s}"], e)

print(json.dumps(summary, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

for i in summary.keys():
  for season in summary[i]['seasons'].keys():
    for episode in range(1, summary[i]['seasons'][season]+1):
      s = "{:02d}".format(int(season))
      e = "{:02d}".format(episode)
      file2chk = f"{summary[i]['prefix']}S{s}E{e}{summary[i]['suffix']}"
      if not os.path.exists(file2chk):
          print(f"missing {file2chk}")
```

first, you need to know the last episode of each season for each movie (first `for`), then check for everything starting from episode 01 (second `for`). Just make sure you have the last episode.

for a movie dir with:

```
name.Joint.Economic.Area.S01E01.720p.NF.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv
name.Joint.Economic.Area.S02E03.720p.NF.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv
```

it outputs:

```
Processing movies/*.mkv..
{
    "movies/name.Joint.Economic.Area.": {
        "prefix": "movies/name.Joint.Economic.Area.",
        "seasons": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 3
        },
        "suffix": ".720p.NF.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv"
    }
}
missing movies/name.Joint.Economic.Area.S02E01.720p.NF.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv
missing movies/name.Joint.Economic.Area.S02E02.720p.NF.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv
```

Comment: the first line `movie_path_orig = sys.argv[1]` seams  does not work for me. and its because the `sys.argv`  has just one item in it and that's the python file path. idk from where should it get the sec item (and i think that's the movie path). should i move the movies the the python file path? or what. i would be grateful if help me. @martin

Comment: you have to point the script to where the movie files are (path directory). So you should always have 2 arguments in argv, one is the script name and the other is the path. Is case this is still confusing to you, you can have movie_path_orig pointing to the dir path where the movies are.